# Link text within labels C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I am working on Visual Studio 2010 using C#.
My query is How do we change the text of the label in one form according to the TextBox in another form?
The text in textBox1(Form A) should be the text of Label1(Form B)
How to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways.  For example, in `FormB` you can expose a method to set the value of the `Label`, something like this:

```
public void SetLabelValue(string value)
{
    someLabel.Text = value;
}
```

Then in `FormA` where you have a reference to an instance of `FormB` you would call that method:

```
someInstanceOfFormB.SetLabelValue(someTextBox.Text);
```

---

Another very similar approach would be to expose a pass-through property on `FormB` for the `Label`'s value directly:

```
public string LabelValue
{
    get { return someLabel.Text; }
    set { someLabel.Text = value; }
}
```

Then you can similarly set it on an instance of `FormB` held elsewhere:

```
someInstanceOfFormB.LabelValue = someTextBox.Text;
```

---

Conversely, if `FormB` holds an instance reference to `FormA` (instead of the other way around as above) then `FormA` can expose a property containing the value of the `TextBox`:

```
public string TextBoxValue
{
    get { return someTextBox.Text; }
}
```

And wherever you have an instance of `FormA` you can get that value, such as on `FormB`:

```
someLabel.Text = someInstanceOfFormA.TextBoxValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the string in a public static prop and use it to get the text.